# I m confused with Object.entries()[i]

Tags: javascript, object, documentation

I have checked this page : [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries)

I dont understand why the index 0 with :

```
const object3 = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(object3)[0]);

// expected output: Array ["100", "a"] <== i thought of this
```

instead the documentation says you get :

```
// expected output: Array ["2", "b"]
```

Someone can explain it why ?

Comment: Per the spec, property names are not reliably ordered. They often happen to be in modern JS interpreters, but you can't count on it. In this case, possibly the property of 100 is seen last because 100 is greater than 2 and 7.

Comment: Objects are unordered. Or, they aren't required to retain a consistent or predictable order of their properties. The engine only has to guarantee that, in a given loop, each property is only visited once. – [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: According to the doc, you can try to use for..in loop to console.log it to know the sequence. However, orders of key in objects are not guaranteed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docs say that `Object.entries` returns an array of given objects enumerable property `[key,value]` pairs . So yes its confusing if you look at this statement

`const object3 = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };`

and end up getting `["2", "b"]` when you call `Object.entries(object3)[0]`.

When you are doing this `Object.entries(object3)[0]` , you are accessing a pair at the index of 0 returned by this function  `Object.entries(object)` . The order of this array has nothing to do with how you defined the `object3` in the first place. The order according to the doc  is the same as the provided by a 
`for...in` loop. I ran the for...in loop on the object and this is what i got as the order.

`2,7,100`.

This is why you are getting `["2", "b"]` instead of `["100", "a"]`. As others have mentioned here , the order seems to be that way because 2<7<100.

Comment: No guarantee about order reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) it says `same order as that provided by a for...in loop` and [for ... in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) states: `A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order` So there is no guarantee about the order of for ... in, Object.keys, and Object.entries

Answer (score 0):

This is because the object has numeric keys and when you manipulate the object with the numeric keys the javascript sort the `key-values` in ascending order of the `key` value and since you have keys `2`, `7`, and `100`. So, check this when you `console.log` the object `Object.entries(object3)` you get that sorted and when you access `[0]` you get `Array ["2", "b"]`

```js
const object3 = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(object3));
```

Further clarification on sorting the object by ascending values of key when they are numeric. The javascript sorts them behind the scenes.

```js
var a = {
  10: 'ten',
  5: 'five',
  11: 'eleven',
  1: 'one'
};
console.log(a);
```

Comment: `JSON object` No such thing.

Comment: JSON is Javascript Object Notation, a way of formatting a string to represent an object. A string can be in JSON format, but an (unserialized) object is just an object.

Comment: @CertainPerformance you should read this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal JSON is a data interchange format, which was based on JS (hence the J in JSON). There is no such a thing as *JSON object*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado cool guys I understood what you meant. Edited

Comment: w3schools has always been a pretty poor reference, and this case just gives more credence to that idea - they're wrong again. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yes, sometimes it scares me how wrong the W3C is.

Comment: @MatusDubrava The problem is not W3C, but w3schools, which is something entirely different, a mediocre tutorial site unrelated to the World Wide Web Consortium.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Of course, I should have at least a coffee before trying to do something :)

Comment: Cool guys. These things really matters

Comment: Do you have a reference that Object.entries orders in alphabetical key order? According to MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) it says `same order as that provided by a for...in loop` and [for ... in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) states: `A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order` So there is no guarantee about the order of for ... in, Object.keys, and Object.entries

Comment: @HMR I haven't mentioned that `Object.entries` orders in alphabetical key order. I have said `Further clarification on sorting the object by ascending values of key when they are numeric. The javascript sorts them behind the scenes.`

Comment: My English not so good but `when you console.log the object Object.entries(object3) you get that sorted` would suggest guarantee of sorted array when using Object.entries. This may be the case now but the standard says **arbitrary order**